# Ajax request to other websites don't work at heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, heroku

I have a Rails app which does an ajax request to the other web site when an user clicks on the button. On localhost it works just fine but at `heroku` it doesn't. It return `"We're sorry, but something went wrong."` (500) and here is the logs

```
Processing by HomeController#some_request as */*
2013-04-09T12:42:33.050720+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"q"=>"another_web_site.com"}
2013-04-09T12:42:33.048011+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/ajax/some_request" for 180.183.158.162 at 2013-04-09 12:42:33 +0000
2013-04-09T12:42:29.793791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application.js host=my_host.org fwd="180.183.158.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-04-09T12:42:54.057280+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-09T12:42:54.057280+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out - connect(2)):
2013-04-09T12:42:54.057280+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-09T12:42:54.057280+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-09T12:42:54.057280+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/domain_info.rb:14:in `who_is'
2013-04-09T12:42:54.057280+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/home_controller.rb:8:in `who_is'
2013-04-09T12:42:54.055802+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21004ms
2013-04-09T12:42:54.059787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/ajax/some_request host=my_host.org fwd="180.183.158.162" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=21017ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Now it's timeout. Right yesterday it was https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h18-request-interrupted where `sock field` was equal to `client`.

Why is that happening?

Comment: As I understand ajax call is a connection between browser and `other web site`. So why do you think heroku is important here?

Comment: Site is working but the ajax call is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your app is doing in `lib/domain_info.rb` is timing out - are you sure that code works from locations other than your machine/localhost? What is that code doing? Sharing that would be helpful.

Comment: why should not it work? I didn't check but it should.

Comment: I don't know - you've got to share that domain_info code for us to have some idea of what it's trying to do and then think about why it wouldn't work from Heroku.

Comment: it just sends http request and nothing else.

Comment: Well, that HTTP request is timing out - and that's what's causing the 500.